# Why isn't this code using function subtyping typechecking with Flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Why isn't this code typechking with [flow](http://flowtype.org)?

```
function runFunction<I, O>( fun: (...args:Array<I>) => O, args:Array<I> ): O {
    var res = fun.apply(null, args);
    return res;
}

function myFun(first: number, second: number): string {
    return first + ", " + second;
}

runFunction(myFun, [1, 2]);
```

I think I am doing everything right, and I still get this

```
function type
Too few arguments (expected default/rest parameters in function)
function

rest array of type parameter I of function call
This type is incompatible with
number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh now I get it. I would have to do this

```
function runFunction<I, O>( fun: (...args:Array<I>) => O, args:Array<I> ): O {
    var res = fun.apply(null, args);
    return res;
}

function myFun(...args:Array<number>): string {
    return args[0] + ", " + args[1];
}

runFunction(myFun, [1, 2]);
```

So, if I get it correctly, "function that takes 2 numbers" is not a subtype of "function that takes any amount of any parameters", even when it logically *is* a subtype.

I am not sure what would be the right solution... I understand, kind of, the logic, but it's confusing slightly.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! I believe you are mistaken that a function of 2 arguments is a subtype of a function of n arguments. In fact, I think the opposite is the case.